# Spring OAuth Bean Exception when adding tokenservice to endpoint config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth, oauth-2.0

when using spring oauth2 and configuring my auth-server endpoint I am running into following exception:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot configure enpdoints
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:137)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot configure enpdoints
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration.init(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration.java:79)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Bean method AuthorizationServerConfig.tokenServices called as a bean reference for type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices] but overridden by non-compatible bean instance of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy105]. Overriding bean of same name declared in: class path resource [com/xxx/yyy/authorization/server/config/AuthorizationServerConfig.class]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.obtainBeanInstanceFromFactory(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:402)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
at com.xxx.yyy.authorization.server.config.AuthorizationServerConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$51b86a07.tokenServices(<generated>)
at com.xxx.yyy.authorization.server.config.AuthorizationServerConfig.configure(AuthorizationServerConfig.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration.init(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration.java:77)
... 38 common frames omitted
```

The config looks like:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() throws Exception {
  DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
  // .... more config stuff
 return defaultTokenServices;
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws 
Exception {
  //@formatter:off
  endpoints.tokenServices(tokenServices()).
  authenticationManager(authenticationManager).approvalStoreDisabled();
  //@formatter:on
}
```

When I take out the endpoints.tokenServices(tokenServices()) it works but then my service becomes not configured by the endpoint ...

Anyone have a tip? Thx

Answer (score 3):

Change the return type of `tokenServices()` to interface `ResourceServerTokenServices`.

Answer (score 0):

@apetrelli's answer is right ,Change the return type of `tokenServices()` to interface `ResourceServerTokenServices`.
Here I am showing some practical example,
I was having same error when I was using DefaultTokenServices  in my ResourceServerConfig class's tokenServices() method as:

```
 @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
```

**But when I changed return type from DefaultTokenServices  to  ResourceServerTokenServices it working fine**. the tokenservice() bean should be different return type in ResourceServerConfig and AuthorizationServerConfig class if you use oauth2 with JWT token.
My AuthorizationServerConfig is

```
package com.myapp.settings.security;

import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenEnhancer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenEnhancerChain;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtTokenStore;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    static final String CLIEN_ID = "<<client - id here>>";
    static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "<<client secret here>>";
    static final String GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD = "password";
    static final String AUTHORIZATION_CODE = "authorization_code";
    static final String REFRESH_TOKEN = "refresh_token";
    static final String IMPLICIT = "implicit";
    static final String SCOPE_READ = "read";
    static final String SCOPE_WRITE = "write";
    static final String TRUST = "trust";
    static final int ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 24 * 60 * 60;
    static final int FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Resource(name = "customUserDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey("ASDFASFsdfsdfsdfsfadsf234asdfasfdas");
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {

        configurer.inMemory().
        withClient(CLIEN_ID)
        .secret(CLIENT_SECRET)
        .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD, AUTHORIZATION_CODE, REFRESH_TOKEN, IMPLICIT)
        .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE, TRUST)
        .accessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS)
        .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(
          Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));
        
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
        .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
        ;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
        return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
       final DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
}
```

And ResourceServerConfig class is

```
package com.myapp.settings.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.ResourceServerTokenServices;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtTokenStore;

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void configure(final ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
//      resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
        
        resources.tokenServices(tokenServices());
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }
 
    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey("ASDFASFsdfsdfsdfsfadsf234asdfasfdas");
        return converter;
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
                authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .antMatchers("/signup/**", "/permitall/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/services/**","/partner/**","/payment/**").permitAll()   
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

}
```